# The repository 'http://http.us.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: debian, apt, repository, ppa

I am trying to setup Debian repositories on a router that runs a Debian-based EdgeOS. I am following [this instruction here](https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/205202560-EdgeRouter-Add-Debian-Packages-to-EdgeOS).

After I add the repository, I get the following error.

```
user@ubnt# sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://http.us.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Err:2 http://http.us.debian.org/debian stretch Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://http.us.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
[edit]
```

When I look inside the `apt` directory I see the following:

```
user@ubnt# ls -lha /etc/apt/sources.list.d
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         232 Jun 24 19:38 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         232 Oct 20  2022 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          80 Jun 24 19:40 stretch.list
[edit]
user@ubnt# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch.list
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free # stretch #
[edit]
```

Comment: If you need to access one of the old distributions of Debian, you can find them at the Debian Archives, https://archive.debian.org/debian/. - https://www.debian.org/distrib/archive

Comment: @IporSircer The instructions specifically say to use the first part for my version of EdgeOS, which corresponds to Debian 9 Stretch. Are you saying that it is now archived as well?

Comment: @IporSircer Alright! That helped. I was able to get it working with some tweaks from that answer. I'll post an answer. Thanks!